# How to set delay to submenu of Pop up menu?

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a contextmenu with submenu. when the Main menu's focus has been lost, the submenu gets hidden suddenly. I want the submenu to be displayed for few seconds after the main menu lost its focus. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Related: [Is is possible to get native menus with Qt4 on Windows 7, 64-bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931464/is-is-possible-to-get-native-menus-with-qt4-on-windows-7-64-bit)