# Is is possible to get native menus with Qt4 on Windows 7, 64-bit?

Tags: qt, user-interface, windows-7, menu, qt4

Applications written in Qt (4) do not have native menus when run on Windows 7, 64-bit. This is true for well-known applications as VLC, Lyx, etc.

Qt menus do not behave as native menus, which can be annoying. As an example, consider the screenshot below.

[image: Qt menu example]

If the mouse is rapidly moved along the red path, the sub menu will close immediately. For native menus in Windows (and on Macs) there is a delay.  This can make it difficult to navigate in the menus, as they will not behave as the user expects.

Is it possible to get native menus in Windows instead?

Comment: i don't think this has to do with `native` menus per se. It's probably some delay option being set through Qt. `native` means how it is drawn for me. Qt definitely draws its controls using native APIs.

Comment: Well, the `behaviour` is not native, at least. I'm not so sure the menus are created with a native API, either. Capturing the HWND handle shows the windows as having no menu.

Comment: You should file it as a Qt bug, if there isn't one already for it.

Comment: Kuba: I'll probably do that in the next couple of days; thanks.

Comment: `QMenu` is a `QWidget`, otherwise it could not be styled.

Answer (score 1):

In Qt5 there's a QPA API for the menus - it is used to create the native Mac menus. It will probably be used on Android soon, and a Windows implementation would be entirely possible. Back-porting to Qt4 would be complex, since the native Mac-menus support was achieved via #ifdefs